# I am trying to fetch the product line of custom module in product line of invoice module in odoo 15

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I have inherited account.move model and added job_card_id field(many2one) in it, as shown as below :

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjxtR.png)

Below given is Image of Selected Job Card :

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLP73.png)

Below given is code of my model and I also tried creating function below fields :

```
    class JobCard(models.Model):
    _name = "job.card"
    _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'mail.activity.mixin']
    _description = "Job Card Master"
    _rec_name = 'job_card_number'

    job_card_number = fields.Char(string='Job Card No.', readonly=True)
    customer_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Customer Name", tracking=True)
    vehicle_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner.line', string="Vehicle", tracking=True,
                                 domain="[('x_customer_id','=',customer_id)]")
    date_time_of_invoice = fields.Datetime(string='Date & Time of Invoice', tracking=True, default=fields.Datetime.now)
    start_date_time = fields.Datetime(string='Start Date & Time', tracking=True)
    end_date_time = fields.Datetime(string='End Date & Time', tracking=True)
    priority = fields.Selection([
        ('0', 'Normal'),
        ('1', 'Low'),
        ('2', 'High'),
        ('3', 'Very High')], string="Priority")  # priority widget
    state = fields.Selection([
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('in_progress', 'In Progress'),
        ('done', 'Done'),
        ('cancel', 'Cancelled')], string="Status", default='draft', required=True)  # status bar

    active = fields.Boolean(string="Active", default=True, tracking=True)

    x_product_ids = fields.Many2many('job.card.line', 'product_id', string="Job Card Details")
    x_quantity_ids = fields.One2many('job.card.line', 'quantity', string="Job Card Details")
    x_price_ids = fields.One2many('job.card.line', 'price', string="Job Card Details")
    x_total_ids = fields.One2many('job.card.line', 'total', string="Job Card Details")
    x_employee_ids = fields.One2many('job.card.line', 'employee_id', string="Job Card Details")
    x_job_card_ids = fields.One2many('job.card.line', 'job_card_id', string="Job Card Details")

    job_card_count = fields.Integer(compute='compute_job_card_count', string='Job Card Count')

    def get_invoice_line_vals(self):
        vals_list = []
        for job_card_line in self.x_product_ids:
            vals_list.append({
                ' price_unit': job_card_line.price_unit,
                'quantity': job_card_line.quantity
            })
        return vals_list
```

Below given is code of inherited model and also added onchange function :

```
class CustomInvoice(models.Model):
_inherit = "account.move"

job_card_id = fields.Many2one('job.card', string="Job Card", domain="[('customer_id','=',partner_id)]",
                              tracking=True)

@api.onchange('job_card_id')
def _onchange_job_card_id(self):
    # creates your invoice lines vals according to your values
    invoice_lines_vals = self.job_card_id.get_invoice_line_vals()
    self.update({'invoice_line_ids': [(5, 0)] + [(0, 0, vals) for vals in invoice_lines_vals]})
```

Below given is code of my job card line :

```
class JobCardLine(models.Model):
_name = "job.card.line"

job_card_id = fields.Many2one('job.card', string="Job Card Id", tracking=True)
product_id = fields.Many2one('product.template', string="Product", tracking=True)
quantity = fields.Integer(string="Quantity", tracking=True)
# price = fields.Char(string="Price")
price = fields.Float(string="Price")
total = fields.Integer(string='Total', compute='_compute_total', tracking=True,
                       help="This field will be calculated from quantity and price !")
employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string="Employee", tracking=True)

x_job_card_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Vehicle Details")

@api.onchange('product_id')
def _on_change_product_id(self):
    self.price = self.product_id.list_price

@api.depends('quantity', 'price')
def _compute_total(self):
    print("self........", self)
    for rec in self:
        rec.total = rec.quantity * rec.price
```

Actually I wanted to add product line of selected job card into Invoice product line automatically when I select the job card.

But I am getting error as shown below :

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYF69.png)

Comment: You got that error because you have no field named `line_ids` in `job.card` model. Maybe you need to change it to `x_product_ids`.

Comment: @Kenly I tried that it is giving error : `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: I wanted to add product line of selected job card into Invoice product line automatically when I select the job card. Am I going in right way ??

Comment: If you clear the invoice lines each time the job card changes, Odoo will remove the manually entered lines

Answer (score 0):

You got that error because you have no field named `line_ids` in `job.card` model. Maybe you need to change it to `x_product_ids`.

The `TyprError` (`int` object is not iterable) is caused by the first tuple passed to the write method :

```
(6, 0, 0)
```

Odoo expects the third parameter to be iterable. If you need to clear the list, use `(5,0)`

Avoid calling the `write` method inside an onchange function. You can read the following danger notice in the official [onchange](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.api.onchange) documentation:

> Danger
> Since `@onchange` returns a recordset of pseudo-records, calling any one of the
>  CRUD methods (`create()`, `read()`, `write()`, `unlink()`) on the
>  aforementioned recordset is undefined behaviour, as they potentially do not exist
>  in the database yet.
> Instead, simply set the record’s field like shown in the example above or call the
>  `update()` method.

***Edit***:

You have two errors in `get_invoice_line_vals` function

**1/ ValueError:**

```
Invalid field ' price_unit' on model 'account.move.line'
```

You need to remove the space at the beginning.

**2/ AttributeError:**

```
'job.card.line' object has no attribute 'price_unit'.
```

Use the `price` field instead.

Comment: I used `(5,0)` in write method , it is not giving any error but when I select job_card it is not setting the product line of invoice. How can I use that `update()` method ??

Comment: You can call `update` method like you call the write method `self.update({'invoice_line_ids': [(5, 0)] + [(0, 0, vals) for vals in invoice_lines_vals]})`. You will need to provide all the required fields.

Comment: Tried doing with update method as you suggested but not getting job card's product line in invoice line.

Comment: I tried your example above, and a line is added to the invoices lines (only the price and quantity) when we select the job card. The problem is that you can't save the invoice because some required fields are not set

Comment: Please, update the question with your code

Comment: Updated question please check and revert.

Comment: I tested your code after correcting the two errors, and it worked as expected